# org capture auto id insert %a

Tags: org-capture

When creating a capture, org capture will auto insert a link which link to the location where the capture action happens, if the capture template contains "%a".

e.g: I'm in heading **A**, and using `M-x org-capture` to create a new heading **B**, **B** will contain a link to **A**.

I found that, the link is an absolute link, e.g: `[[A][file:\path\to\file:*A]]`.

My question is, how to change the style of the auto insert link? I want to use an id like link, e.g: `[id:foo]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will use an id-style link when capture action happen in a org heading with ID property.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-link-parameters
  '("test/store-link"
    :store test/store-link))
(defun test/store-link ()
  (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (let ((id (org-entry-get 
                (point) "ID")))
      (when id
        (org-link-store-props 
          :type "test/store-link"
          :link (concat "id:" id)
          :description id)))))
```